# How to engage users after the data has be called and stored and UI is building

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

There is a delay before the UI is built as the UI is pretty complex. After the data has been called and stored I can use Loaders but only while making a service call not during the UI construction.
Has anyone faced the same problem and do you have any solution ?

Comment: Is this when you initialize the App, or does it occur everytime you navigate to that Page in specific ? Depending on your answer you might want to check this out [SplashScreen](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/splash-screen/)

Comment: @Greggz No it is not a startup page I am looking for a specific page